# How to update/rename file of Google Drive with drive_API v3 in Swift?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, google-drive-api, swift5

I am trying to rename/update file content of Google Drive in the scope of `kGTLRAuthScopeDriveAppdata` with help of Drive_API v3 found from [google developer documentation](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/update#objective-c).

My converted code is below:

```
func renameFile(fileId: String, newTitle: String,newdata: Data, completionBlock: @escaping (GTLRDrive_File?, Error?) -> Void) {
    
    let query = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesGet.query(withFileId: fileId)
    self.service.executeQuery(query) { (ticker, file, err) in
        if err == nil {
            
            let file = file as! GTLRDrive_File
            print(file.name ?? "","get file name")
            file.name = newTitle
            file.descriptionProperty = "new description"
            file.mimeType = "*/*"
            
            let uploadParam = GTLRUploadParameters(data: newdata,mimeType: "*/*")
            let updateQuery = GTLRDriveQuery_FilesUpdate.query(withObject: file, fileId: fileId, uploadParameters: uploadParam) 

            updateQuery.keepRevisionForever = true
            self.service.executeQuery(updateQuery) { (ticket, uFile, err) in
                if err == nil {
                    let updated = uFile as! GTLRDrive_File
                    completionBlock(updated,nil)
                } else {
                    print("rename not worked error occur")
                    completionBlock(nil,err)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("main error occur")
            completionBlock(nil,err)
        }
    }
}
```

but I don't know what's wrong with above code and i'm getting this error.

> **Error Domain=com.google.HTTPStatus Code=403 "(null)" UserInfo={data={length = 239, bytes = 0x7b226572 726f7222 3a7b2265 72726f72 ... 61626c65 2e227d7d }, data_content_type=application/json; charset=UTF-8}**

I asked for solution on [Github](https://github.com/google/google-api-objectivec-client-for-rest/issues/43) too, But not getting any proper answer.

Thanks.

Comment: @DaImTo patch is not available in v3. How can i write code ? see above code for update and how can i use patch in v3

Comment: which line is trhowing the error thats not an error i would expect to come from executeQuery but rather one from the autorization code.

Comment: @DaImTo yes, as expect this query is execute but error not successful and give 403 error